# Definition for average- Python

Tags: python

I have a list which is made up of little lists inside. Each little list consists of 15 elements, and hence this average definition works. However, if i change each little list to have a different number of elements, this code obviously doesnt work, how can i change it so that it works no matter how many elements are in each little list? Thanks

```
def avelist(inputlist):
    total = 0
    for row in inputlist:
        total += sum(row)
    return total/ (15* len(inputlist)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just keep track of the number of items:

```
def avelist(inputlist):
    total = 0
    items = 0

    for row in inputlist:
        total += sum(row)
        items += len(row)

    return total / items
```

Comment: thanks so much, how can i now make 'items' equal the number of little lists that are in the  bigger list? I try len(inputList) but it doesnt seem to work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to flatten your nested list and do `sum` and `len` directly:

```
from itertools import chain

def avelist(inputlist):
    lst = list(chain.from_iterable(inputlist))
    return sum(lst) / len(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def avelist(inputlist):
    total = 0
    totallen = 0
    for row in inputlist:
        total += sum(row)
        totallen += len(row)
    return total/ totallen
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.